# Every character is a state?

Tags: solution-verification, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Then

> $\phi:A\to \mathbb C$ is called a character if it is a non-zero homomorphism.

A character has the following properties:

(1) $\phi(1)=1$.

(2) $\phi(x)\in sp(x):=\{\lambda: \lambda -x \text{ is not invertible}\}$ for all $x\in A$.

(3) $\phi$ is bounded with $\|\phi\|\leq 1$.

Now according to me, (1) and (3) imply:

(4) $\|\phi\|= 1$.

And (2) implies:

(5) $\phi\geq 0$.

> $\phi:A\to \mathbb C$ is called a state if it is positive, linear and $\|\phi\|= 1$.

**Question:** Is it correct that using (4) and (5), every character is a state?

Comment: Where do you doubt your reasoning?

Comment: It's just something which seem obvious to me but I can't find it stated explicitly in my notes or other places. However, I have seen a proof of another theorem, which proves it as a part. So I was just wondering why so many steps when every character is already a state?

Comment: @nicrot000 No. It doesn't. But my question is only if every character is a state not conversely.

Comment: In this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372171/characters-of-a-c-algebra characters are characterized as special states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Note that more generally, every $*$-homomorphism $\pi: A \to B$ between $C^*$-algebras is positive because
$$\pi(a^*a) = \pi(a)^*\pi(a) \ge 0.$$